# generate pdf/xl report from html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, report

Is there any way to generate pdf/Excl reports from html?
    thanks...

Comment: Do you want populate PDF/Excel report on client side?

Comment: can you try this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/139496/How-to-convert-html-file-into-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't clarify what you are trying to achieve. But to give answer to question, no you cannot generate pdf/Excel reports from html, for that you need to use server side languages like Java/PHP/C# etc. If you clarify question, we can give appropriate answer.